# How to initial "static const char * []" in class member?[C++]

Tags: c++

When I am doing my homework, the question ask me to finish the given class:

```
//Card.hpp
class Card {
private:
    static const char* faceNames[totalFaces];
};
```

I write mycode in `Card.cpp`:

```
const char* faceNames[Card::totalFaces] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
```

I use VS2017 to build it, but it shows that

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static char const * * Card::faceNames" (?faceNames@Card@@0PAPBDA)
```

How should I do?

Comment: thx, i think i code so much that i become fool……

Answer (score 1):

You can define it outside the class without specifying the size. You don't have to specify the size again. Note the `::` requirement for defining members outside class.

```
const char* Card::faceNames[] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b320f25e380adff)

Comment: You can even remove the size specification from the class declaration too.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally defined an unrelated array `faceNames` when you meant to define the static member.  You need to name the class static member using `::` notation:

```
const char* Card::faceNames[Card::totalFaces] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
```